# TypeScript gives an error Nest.js is not a module

Tags: typescript, module, nestjs

I'm using the Nest.js to build my project, but there is an error I encounter in the middle of my work. I didn't find any solution to this issue. I'm exporting a function from the file and importing it in the controller, but it gives error that it's not a module there is no export going on, but I'm exporting the function as you see in the code:

```js
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
export class AdminGuard extends AuthGuard ('admin'){
    constructor(){
     
        super();
    }
}
```

to export this

```js
export * from './admin-jwt.strategy'`
```

Controller:

```js
import { Controller, Get,UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { JwtGuard,AdminGuard } from 'src/auth/guard';
import { DynamicRole } from 'src/auth/decorator';

@UseGuards(AdminGuard,DynamicRole)
@DynamicRole('superadmin', 'support')

@Controller('user')
export class UserController {
    constructor(private userservice:UserService){}
    @Get('me')
    getme(){
        return this.userservice.getme();
    }

}
```

[This error is shown in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpdiK.png)
I tried to restart the server and check the `tsconfig.json`, and also check the dist folder for any errors, but found nothing.

tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ES2021",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false
  }
}
```

I also tried to change the `commonjs` with the ECMAScript 6, but other error pops up: built in module not found, like as you see in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOtQN.png).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the import

```
import { JwtGuard,AdminGuard } from 'src/auth/guard';
```

Use **../** instead of **src**

```
import { JwtGuard,AdminGuard } from '../auth/guard';
```